# My Firebase AdsMob didn't appear's when run

Tags: android, firebase

i'm tried to add Ads to my app, this is my first time to do this and following some tutorial but the ads didn't appear into my app.

My app already created before i'm adding the ads.

Adding classpath to project gradle

Adding implementation to app gradle

add adviewlayout in activity xml

Classpath in projectgradle :

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Implementation in app gradle :

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   MobileAds.initialize(this,"APP_ID");

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Adunitid and app_id stored in string value

I also created AdMob account and linked with firebase, copy and replace old JSON file but when i run the app the ads didn't appear.

Comment: You just need to wait a little. Your ad id is newly created so it will take some time to fetch ads from google servers.Also the easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit ID for Android banners: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

Comment: ok i created it about 6 hours ago, are you sure nothing wrong in code ?

Comment: Yes,but confirm your banner is and ad id inside your code.

Comment: are we should replace JSON config file everytime we add new adunit ?

Comment: JSON config measn googlejason file of firebase?

Comment: After two days the ads still not appear, so i tried create new project only for testing firebase ads and the result are same the ads didn't show when app run.

Comment: Have you try using test id?

Comment: Using test id run succesfuly, so its all about my app id and unit id... what went wrong and what should i do, is there any further step to activate the admob account so my app and unit id is usable.?

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest>
<application>
    <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
</application>
```

Add this on your manifest also check for internet permission

Comment: In the manifest ,meta data  already  wrote and internet pernission is allowed but the ads still not appears

Comment: I think it because i'm not yet fill payment info required while in all tutorial i saw they didn't mention about filling payment info.

Comment: does dummy ads working ? no need to fill payment info,only need when you reach your threshhold payment amount(100$).

Comment: Dummy work fine,while if i paste my ad unit and app id the ads not work.